# mongoose group with subdocument properties

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was trying something with events and had to run a group by query but I couldn't get through it because it was mostly on subdocument.

Here is my DB currently:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5bbb6e1c7f3fc62db401d05a"), 
"type" : "ADD_BOOK", 
"metadata" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbb6e1c7f3fc62db401d05b"), 
    "name" : "ad", 
    "author" : "ad", 
    "imgUrl" : "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/6/60/No_Image_Available.png"
}, 
"timestamp" : 1539010076240.0, 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5bbb736ad441d505589ccecc"), 
"type" : "ADD_BOOK", 
"metadata" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbb736ad441d505589ccecb"), 
    "name" : "ada", 
    "author" : "ada", 
    "imgUrl" : "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/6/60/No_Image_Available.png"
}, 
"timestamp" : 1539011434826.0, 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5bbb7373d441d505589ccecd"), 
"type" : "DELETE_BOOK", 
"metadata" : {
    "_id" : "5bbb736ad441d505589ccecb"
}, 
"timestamp" : 1539011443792.0, 
"__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

and I want the output to be like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bbb736ad441d505589ccecb"),
    "books": [
        {
            "type": "ADD_BOOK",
            "metadata": {
                "_id": ObjectId("5bbb736ad441d505589ccecb"),
                "name": "ada",
                "author": "ada",
                "imgUrl": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/6/60/No_Image_Available.png"
            }
        }
        {
            "type": "DELETE_BOOK",
            "metadata": {
              "_id": ObjectId("5bbb736ad441d505589ccecb")
            }
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bbb6e1c7f3fc62db401d05b"),
    "books": [
        {
            "type": "ADD_BOOK",
            "metadata": {
                "_id": ObjectId("5bbb6e1c7f3fc62db401d05b"),
                "name": "ad",
                "author": "ad",
                "imgUrl": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/simpsons/images/6/60/No_Image_Available.png"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

My current implementation tries something like this:

```
db.bookevents.aggregate([
    { $match: { }},
    { $group: { _id: "$metadata._id", books: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }
])
```

This doesn't work as expected. I am trying to read the documentation but I can't figure this one out yet.

Is it possible that the solution to this is something else and not `$group`? Also can we put a `$sort` on timestamp for each `books[]`?

P.S. I know the question is mostly code but I don't know how to put it in any other way.

Comment: What is not working here ? Sorting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `3` groups instead of expected `2` because `metadata._id` for `DELETE_BOOK` is of type **string** whereas all the others are of type **ObjectId**. You have to manually fix that or if can use MongoDB 4.0 then you can use [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) operator to convert that value before `$group`. Additionally you can apply `$sort` before grouping and get rid of unnecessary fields using `$project`. Try:

```
db.bookevents.aggregate([
    { $addFields: { "metadata._id": { $toObjectId: "$metadata._id" } } }, // or fix manually
    { $sort: { timestamp: 1 } },
    { $group: { _id: "$metadata._id", books: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
    { $project: { "books.timestamp": 0, "books.value": 0, "books.__v": 0 } }
])
```

Comment: In the same example, suppose I want to implement search and I  want to `$match` something like this: `{ $match: { 'metadata.name': { $regex: 'ad' } }}`, then it doesn't give the same result ('DELETE_BOOK' event is not in result). For this, do I have to change the way I handle data in the metadata field? or is there a way which returns `metadata._id` of matching `metadata.name` and the remaining query remains same? The end result should be the same.

Comment: @Ashniu123 you can try to put your regex after `$group` which will check if array contains any element with specified condition, like `{ $match: { "books.type": { $regex: 'AD*' } } }`

Comment: I want to do the regex match on the `metadata.name` field only. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Ashniu123 ah I see, so you can try `{ $match: { "books.metadata.name": { $regex: 'ad' } } }` after `$group`